# How to access capture group instead of fullstring match?

Tags: php, preg-match, capture-group

I am using `preg_match()` to search in a file and list the results.

In my file I have:

```
city 1 | address 1 | phone 1
city 2 | address 2 | phone 2
city 3 | address 3 | phone 3
```

If I search for `address 1` for example, it will show me the full line.

Is there any way to show only 'address 1'?

Comment: Please show your code and explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: you want to search 'address 1' and return 'address 1' what the purpose ?

Comment: Let say I have somewhere in the list 'address 554'. They are divided by | 
I need when I search for 554 to get the full | address 554 |

Comment: @qqq123 You should update your question with any new information rather than offer new details via comment.  There is still insufficient information to provide an accurate/refined answer.

Comment: @qqq123 You must show your code, then we can help you properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Subpatterns. You can put Subpatterns in your Regex with these Brackets:

```
()
```

Everything between is your Subpattern and will be added to your Array with the Matches, if there is a Match.

Compare this:

```
$subject = 'thiswhatiamlookingforallday';
preg_match('/.*whatiamlookingfor.*/', $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

to this:

```
$subject = 'thiswhatiamlookingforallday';
preg_match('/.*(whatiamlookingfor).*/', $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

It should give you a hint of what is to do.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using the parameter *matches*, isn't it?

> If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search.
>   $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern,
>   $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured
>   parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: When seeking clarification about the question and offering manual references, do so as comments not answers.  This question lacks the necessary detail to provide accurate answers.